# Why doesn't Assert::AreEqual in the VS UnitTesting framework work with std::string?

Tags: c++, string, unit-testing, visual-c++, std

I am trying to do a unit test on some c++ code but am running into some trouble.

I have something similar to the following lines of code...

```
std::string s1 = obj->getName();
std::string s2 = "ExpectedName";
Assert::AreEqual(s1, s2, "Unexpected Object Name");
```

And I'm getting the following compiler error...

```
error C2665: 'Microsoft::VisualStudio::TestTools::UnitTesting::Assert::AreEqual' :
none of the 15 overloads could convert all the argument types
```

It seems like it should be a match with [the following overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243446%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

```
AreEqual<(Of <(T>)>)(T, T, String)
```

Isn't the above overload a template overload that should support any object, as long as arguments 1 and 2 are of the same type? Or am I missing something?

Is there some other way that I can accomplish this Assert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hacked up a bit of a workaround so that integers are compared instead of strings:

```
Assert::AreEqual(0, s1.compare(s2), "Unexpected Object Name");
```

In the future, we will likely switch to native C++ unit testing, but in the meantime, this does the trick. Obviously the messaging for this isn't very helpful

```
Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<0>. Actual:<1>. Unexpected Trajectory Name
```

But it's better than nothing.

Comment: Another workaround (for strings only without additional effort) would be to use the [built-in marshaling library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384865(VS.100).aspx): `Assert::AreEqual(marshal_as<String^>(s1), marshal_as<String^>(s2), L"Unexpected Object Name");`. +1 though, I think your workaround is creative. :-]

Answer (score 4):

You're attempting to use the *managed* unit testing framework with *native* types – this simply isn't going to work without marshaling the objects into managed types first.

VS2012 now comes with a [native C++ unit testing framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh270864.aspx); using this framework instead, your code could work by changing `"Unexpected Object Name"` to a wide string (prefix with `L`) and calling [the following overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh694604.aspx#BKMK_General_Are_Equal):

```
template<typename T> 
static void AreEqual(
    const T& expected, 
    const T& actual, 
    const wchar_t* message = NULL, 
    const __LineInfo* pLineInfo = NULL)
```

Comment: I appreciate the explanation as to why it's not working, but I don't have access to VS2012.

Comment: @sgryzko : Then your best bet is to use some third-party native C++ testing framework – using a managed framework to test native types is 2000% more effort than it's worth. [Boost.Test](http://www.boost.org/libs/test/) might be a good start.

Comment: Might I suggest [xUnit++](https://bitbucket.org/moswald/xunit) instead of Boost.Test? It is (in my admittedly biased opinion) a little simpler to get started.

Answer (score 3):

If we are trying to stay in un-managed C++, and we don't care what the error message looks like, this is probably a better option than the accepted answer:

`Assert::IsTrue(s1==s2)`

By better, I mean it is at least easy to read.

Answer (score 1):

I believe solution is to us L prefix before string

```
      Assert::AreEqual<bool>(true, dict->IsBeginWith("", ""), L"Empty");
```

You can also try case it like this, which give you wrong results, but lead to right direction of understanding of issue

```
   Assert::AreEqual<bool>(true, dict->IsBeginWith("", ""), (wchar_t*)"Empty"); //Empty
   Assert::AreEqual(true, dict->IsBeginWith("A", "A"), (wchar_t*)"Empty2");
   Assert::AreEqual(true, dict->IsBeginWith("A", "a"), (wchar_t*)""); //CAPITAL LETTER Check
```